# How to filter rows from various string patterns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a large dataframe, in which there is a column with number and letter codes. Something like this:

| ID | death_cause |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | K703 |
| 2 | N19X |
| 3 | C069 |
| 4 | C07X |
| 5 | D181 |
| 6 | R99X |
| 7 | D371 |
| 8 | E117 |
| 9 | D489 |
| 10 | D500 |

I need to filter and keep all codes starting with the letter C and codes starting with the letter D, but only with the numbers from 0 to 48 (i.e. D00, D10, D20, D48), data starting with D49 onwards are no longer needed.

I have managed to filter out the letter C codes, since it is easy to just ask to keep the characters starting with the letter C with dplyr and stringr.

```
df_filtered <- df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(death_cause, "^C"))
```

However, I need to keep the specific D-codes as well.
One idea I had is to create a vector with the characters of the D-codes

```
D_codes <- paste("D", 00:48, sep = "")
```

My question is how to filter those other character patterns next to the C codes with dplyr and stringr (tidyverse, in general) functions.

I tried:

```
 df_filtered <- df %>% 
      filter(str_detect(death_cause, "^C") | str_detect(death_cause, D_codes ) )
```

Any help you can give me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think you can probably get away with `df %>% filter(grepl("^C|^D", death_cause), death_cause < "D49")`.

Comment: alternatively `df %>% filter(str_detect(death_cause,'^[C|D]') & between(as.numeric(str_remove_all(death_cause,'\\D')),0,48))`

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track. You’ll want to pad the single digit numerals for your D codes:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

D_codes <- str_c("D", str_pad(0:48, 2, pad = "0"))
```

And just use `%in%` rather than `str_detect()`:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(str_starts(death_cause, "C") | death_cause %in% D_codes))
```

(Also note `str_starts()` as an alternative to `str_detect()` in this case.)